# SQLite, how to use expression in datetime modifier

Tags: sqlite

In short: I need to calculate the ending datetime given starting time and length in minutes.

I have a table with columns `StartTime` (type datetime) and `LengthMinutes` (type int). To calculate the ending time I would need some sql like this:

```
select datetime(StartTime, '+LengthMinutes minutes') from my_table;
```

How do I refer to the column LengthMinutes from within the modifier?

**Edited:** solved using dan04's suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Should you not mark @dan04's answer as 'accepted'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT datetime(StartTime, '+' || LengthMinutes || ' minutes') FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select datetime(strftime('%s',StartTime)+lengthMinutes*60,'unixepoch') from my_table;
```